# Duplicate TOC in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

In this svelte component, the table of contents of the article is duplicated in a special window on the right side of the screen when the table of contents in the body of the article scrolls up. When you go to another page of the article, where there is another table of contents in the body of the article, the table of contents of the previous article is saved in a special window on the right side of the screen. It is unclear why this is happening. How to solve the problem. The table of contents itself cannot be touched, as it is generated automatically using the remark-toc plugin.

```
<script>
// @ts-nocheck

    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import { scale, fade } from 'svelte/transition'

    let tableOfContents = null
    let showToc = false
    let showAside = false


    function getTableOfContents() {
        const postTableOfContentsEl = document.querySelector('#в-этой-статье + ol')
        if (postTableOfContentsEl) {
            tableOfContents = postTableOfContentsEl.outerHTML
        }
    }

    function onAside() {
        const targetEl = document.querySelector('#в-этой-статье + ol')
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
            entry.boundingClientRect.bottom < 0 ? (showAside = true) : (showAside = false)
        })
        observer.observe(targetEl)

        return () => {
            observer.unobserve(targetEl)
        }
    }

    onMount(() => {
        onAside()
        getTableOfContents()
    })

    function toggleToc() {
        showToc = !showToc
    }
</script>

{#if tableOfContents}
    {#if showAside}
        <div in:fade={{ duration: 200 }} out:fade={{ duration: 200}}>
            {#if showToc}
                <div class="toc" class:active={showToc} transition:scale={{ start: 0, duration: 300, delay: 0 }}>
                    <p class="toc-title">В этой статье</p>
                    {@html tableOfContents}
                </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
        <button on:click={toggleToc} in:fade={{ duration: 200 }} out:fade={{ duration: 200}}>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="800" class="cf-icon-svg" viewBox="-2.5 0 19 19"><path d="M2.85 4.836a1.03 1.03 0 0 1-1.029 1.03h-.003a1.03 1.03 0 1 1 0-2.059h.003a1.03 1.03 0 0 1 1.03 1.03zm0 4.346a1.03 1.03 0 0 1-1.029 1.03h-.003a1.03 1.03 0 1 1 0-2.059h.003a1.03 1.03 0 0 1 1.03 1.03zm0 4.346a1.03 1.03 0 0 1-1.029 1.03h-.003a1.03 1.03 0 1 1 0-2.059h.003a1.03 1.03 0 0 1 1.03 1.03zm1.13-8.692a1.03 1.03 0 0 1 1.029-1.029h7.173a1.03 1.03 0 1 1 0 2.058H5.009a1.03 1.03 0 0 1-1.03-1.029zm9.231 4.347a1.03 1.03 0 0 1-1.029 1.029H5.009a1.03 1.03 0 1 1 0-2.059h7.173a1.03 1.03 0 0 1 1.03 1.03zm0 4.345a1.03 1.03 0 0 1-1.029 1.03H5.009a1.03 1.03 0 1 1 0-2.059h7.173a1.03 1.03 0 0 1 1.03 1.03z"/></svg>
        </button>
    {/if}

{/if}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use sveltes onNavigate()  function to trigger a reload from the TOC component?

Comment: also doesn't help